# Chart.js show x-axis data from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am working on the chart.js vertical chart and I want to make a slight change in the way it displays.

Basically the first data will be displayed from the left but I want to display first data from right. Is that possible?

Here is the working version of what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/wxaL6en0/4/

```
   options: {

      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,

      legend: {
        display: false,
      }
   }
```

This is what i have done for the option.

The result I am expecting is, `April` to be on the right and first bar to display on the right.

I am not sure this is possible since I didn't find any solution over the internet. But I hope someone tried this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that **Chart.js 2.8.0 supports reverse boolean parameter only for ticks object of yAxes.**

This means, that without hacking or monkey patching it cannot be done within Chart.js API.

Also this dirty solution I came up with seems to be over-engineered, because simply changing dataset.data array item by referring to it by its index does not trigger Chart.js animations properly, therefore one needs to use splice.

**Explanation:**

Actually the idea is pretty simple:

In order to show bars from right to left for a priori known number of them 
 
One needs to first create an array of length equal to number of bars and fill it with nulls. 
 
In other words an array containing as many nulls as there are bars to be displayed.

Then each new value has to be inserted (using splice) from the right (end of the array) at first index under which array item is null or just simply at correct index, counting down from the array.length - 1 to 0.

**"Visualisation":**

```js
let value = 1;

const graphData = Array(3).fill(null);
console.log(graphData)

for(let i = graphData.length - 1; i >= 0; --i){
    graphData.splice(i, 1, value++);
    console.log(graphData)
}
```

**Example:**

```js
class GraphController {
    size = 0;
    data = [];
    labels = [];
    graphData = [];
    ctx = null;
    chart = null;

    constructor(size, data, labels, canvasId) {
        this.size = size;
        this.data = data;
        this.labels = labels;

        this.ctx = document.getElementById(canvasId).getContext('2d');

        this.graphData = Array(size).fill(null);
    }

    fetchAndDraw(index = 1) {
        const item = this.data[index - 1];
        if (item.TotalReward) {
            this.graphData[this.size - index] = item.TotalReward;
        }

        if (index > 1 && index < this.size) {
            this.chart.data.datasets[0].data.splice(this.size - index, 1, item.TotalReward);
            this.chart.update();
        } else {
            if (this.chart) {
                this.chart.destroy();
            }

            this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: this.labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        data: [...this.graphData],
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: '#d5d5d5',
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        enabled: false,
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            barPercentage: 1.0,
                            categoryPercentage: 0.55,
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false,
                                color: '#fff',
                                drawBorder: false,
                                zeroLineColor: '#fff'
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                fontFamily: '"Avenir Next", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"',
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontColor: '#fff',
                                padding: 15,
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            categoryPercentage: 0.8,
                            barPercentage: 0.8,
                            gridLines: {
                                display: false,
                                color: '#fff',
                                drawBorder: false,
                                zeroLineColor: '#fff'
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                min: 0,
                                stepSize: 10,
                                fontFamily: '"Avenir Next", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"',
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontColor: '#fff',
                                padding: 10,
                                callback: function (value) {
                                    return '$' + value;
                                }
                            }
                        }],
                    },
                },
            });
        }

        index++;
        if (index <= this.size) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.fetchAndDraw(index);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}



const data = [
    { "Month": "April ‘18", "TotalReward": 10.37 },
    { "Month": "May ‘18", "TotalReward": 18.11 },
    { "Month": "June ‘18", "TotalReward": 25.49 },
    { "Month": "January", "TotalReward": 35.55 },
    { "Month": "February", "TotalReward": 50.25 },
    { "Month": "March", "TotalReward": 59.15 },
]

const rewardLabels = ["April ‘18", "May ‘18", "June ‘18", "January", "February", "March"].reverse();

const graph = new GraphController(6, data, rewardLabels, 'rewardChart');
graph.fetchAndDraw();
```

```css
.chart-wrap {
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-wrap">
  <canvas id="rewardChart" width="600" height="165"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: it would if the first bar would be displayed at `April`. will that be possible?

Comment: Yes it will. In my first example reverse on data was missing.

Comment: hi there? do you think there will be any solution for that?

Comment: It looks like it cannot be solved by any parameter of Chart.JS API, so one has to use some kind of monkey patch.

Comment: looks perfect. what did you actually change from the previous code? could you briefly explain in the answer so it will be easier for future reference?

Comment: I have added explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the reverse option:

```
let isRightToLeft = true;
chart.options = {
      scales: {
        x: {
          reverse: isRightToLeft ? true : false,
        }
      }
    };
```