# Text Direction for axis labels in Chart.js

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, primeng

I'm using chart.js in angular8 (in Primeng). I need to set these options in my chart:

- for y-axis ticks => textDirection: 'ltr'
- for x-axis ticks => textDirection: 'rtl'

for example,
I have done this for tooltip by textDirection:

```
 options = {
   tooltips: {
    textDirection: 'rtl', //make tooltip text rtl
  }
}
```

Is there any way do something like that to my axes?

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58803539/13331446

Comment: I have found a link easier: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/129#issuecomment-120543234 . You can choose the best option

Comment: thanks. I implemented sth like first link for my data, but I think that is dirty solution :(

Comment: and about your second link, I wanna make each text rtl, but reverse tag make all labels position reverse (it is like global rtl and is not like textDirection)

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem: the date's `dd` and `MMM` were messed up regardless of the [display formatting](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats) order. Unfortunately, ChartJS doesn't support RTL text direction officially.

One possible simple solution is directly setting the canvas element's `dir` attribute using a [custom plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html).

```js
import { Chart } from 'chart.js'

const RtlChartPlugin = {
  id: 'rtl-chart-plugin',
  beforeDraw: (chart: Chart) => {
    chart.canvas.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl')
  }
}

Chart.register(
  // ...
  RtlChartPlugin
)
```

As a timeline axis user, it was also nessecsry for me to add a [displayFormat](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats).

```js
time: {
  displayFormats: {
    day: 'dd MMM'
  }
}
```

I'm not sure it's still relevant but I hope others will find it helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately it messes up with [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) but in some cases its actually a nice solution :)

Comment: @IlanYashuk It is very unfortunate, as my solution wraps all the canvas it's very likely to interfere with other plugins. With the core ChartJS library, it seems to work fine. I'm sorry I couldn't assist with your case.